# Add a custom item to eloquent collection

Tags: laravel, collections, eloquent

I am using Laravel 7.

I have `Category` model. I sent categories as API with laravel resources. But now I want to add "all" value to categories.

Controller:

```
'categories' => CategoryResource::collection(Category::all()->push([
      'id' => 0,
      'name' => "All",
      'subcategories' => []
 ]))
```

Resource:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
     return [
          'id' => $this->id,
          'name' => $this->name,
          'subcategories' => SubcategryResource::collection($this->subcategories)
     ];
}
```

Also, I wanted to add this custom value to the beginning of the collection.

But I am getting this error:

> Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Please, help me. How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you're trying to add an item to the collection which is not a category model. `$this` in the resource reverts to the given model. However, you pass in an array so there is no model.

So try this instead

```
$allCategory = new Category(['id' => 0, 'name' => 'All']);

'categories' => CategoryResource::collection(Category::all()->prepend($allCategory));
```

I got these from: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/add-a-custom-value-to-eloquent-collection

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `$this->id` with `$this['id']`

If that works your query is returning an array not an object.

Comment: It is not a solution. Is there any other better solution?